# Is it possible to run a batch file which runs a executable jar on a different JVM?

Tags: batch-file, jvm, runtime, jrockit

I have a web project that picks up the report generated using batch and streams to the servletOutputstream. This batch is run using task scheduler at regular intervals. The problem here is, the report that the user downloads is not real time.

Generating and downloading the report on a click of a button without using batch is not possible as the server is not capable of it-Multiple DB calls and multiple cursors are being used and the application goes OOM, memory tuning didn't work at all-(weblogic10.3.6, jrockit1.6). The batch is set up such that it uses Sun JVM, with 1024m heap space and it is working well.

Now, I want to call this Batch on click of a button and I want it to run on the JVM specified in the .bat file-Sun JVM1.6- not the already loaded Jrockit. Is it possible to do this? If yes, how?

Any help on this is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: do you mean something like this: `"C:\Program Files\Java\j2re1.4.2_04\bin\javaw.exe" -jar Myfile.jar` ?   (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986531/can-i-run-more-than-one-jvm-on-my-single-pc)

Comment: yes, it's what we have in the batch script. Consider I have another application running on weblogic, JRockit and I want to invoke the afore mentioned batch from this application. Is it possible?(could correlate with RMI)

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question.. can you not use runtime.exec to run the batch file? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615948/how-do-i-run-a-batch-file-from-my-java-application