# how to start jvm and can we have multiple jvm running on a single system?

Tags: java, jvm

I had been asked this question in interview, how to start jvm and can we have multiple jvm running on a single system?

Comment: Open up many java programs.

Comment: yes you can have multiple jvm, each java program is a jvm itself.

Comment: @3kings .. that means whenever we open any java program.. jvm automatically started? or it is started when program is compiled?

Comment: Each Java program you run, will have a different JVM instance.

Comment: You can run multiple program on a machines, and a JVM is just another program.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986531/can-i-run-more-than-one-jvm-on-my-single-pc

Comment: @UDKOX  only in case of starting  you apps  with a  java  command  line !

Answer (score 12):

**Each Java application running uses an independent JVM.**

Each JVM is a separate process, and they do not share stacks, heaps. Only common core JVM and native libraries will be shared.

You can have n number of application running on single machine/server box, and so as n number of JVM's.

Launching multiple java processes will create JVM for you.

In all you can have any number of JVM running in your machine, with even different JDK versions.

Answer (score 5):

> How to start jvm.

If you have a Java JRE or JDK, then the simple way to start a JVM is to run the `java` command.  For example:

```
 java -jar someapp.jar
```

starts a JVM that runs the application in the supplied ("executable") JAR file.

> Can we have multiple jvm running on a single system?

Yes.  Provided you have enough memory.

On a typical OS, each JVM runs as a process.  Assuming that the OS allows you to launch multiple processes, you can run multiple JVMs.  (This is certainly true for Windows, Linux, MacOSX and other varieties of UNIX on which Java runs.)

Answer (score 0):

The way to start a jvm is by invoking the main, either by invoking a jar using `java -jar MyJar` or by simply running main class from an IDE.

Yes, Multiple jvm instances can be run on a single machine, they all will have their own memory allocated.
There will be that many jvms as many main programs you run.