# Is there a way to run same junit test on two different jvm

Tags: java

```
@Test
    public void testMain1() throws Exception {

        Runnable t1 = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String[] str1 = {"noproxyconfig/serverA.dat"};
                try {
                    SIMLConcentratorMain.main(str1);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        Runnable t2 = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String[] str2 = {"noproxyconfig/serverB.dat"};
                try {
                    SIMLConcentratorMain.main(str2);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };
        new Thread(t1).start();
        new Thread(t2).start();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
}
```

Basically I am trying to start main method two times with different arguments (which is starting two servers) . Right now I am achieving this using multithreading but I think its running in same JVM. But I want to start both servers in different JVM. I created Juint test and created two thread and calling both threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Remote Method Invocation (RMI) you can run on two different machine(so two JVM)

you can use virtual machine

1-Create Rmi Methode

2-Start servers in many machines

3-Start your test

Comment: Thank you! But what my question is when I start my test it should start Runnable t1 in one jvm and Runnable t2 in another jvm.

Comment: @p50 Each JVM is a separate process, and they do not share stacks, heaps. Only common core JVM and native libraries will be shared.

You can have n number of application running on single machine/server box, and so as n number of JVM's.

Launching multiple java processes will create JVM for you.. so if you want test in many jvm you should separate your code and start it seperatly   --- you can see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298011/how-to-start-jvm-and-can-we-have-multiple-jvm-running-on-a-single-system